# How to get a list of states which come before a given state with Ruby `state_machine` gem?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, state-machine

Considering the [state_machine](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine) gem, how does one select a set of state names/symbols that come before a given state?

Lets say I have four states: `:pending`, `:signature_needed`, `:ordered`, `:finalized`. Assume a linear progression from the initial (`:pending`) to the final (`:finalized`) state.

How would I get all states which come before `:ordered`? I would expect a result like `[:pending, :signature_needed]`.

Note: I just realized, after trying to figure out why this functionality is not provided, that `state_machine` is [not currently supported](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine/issues/343) (as I was going to make a PR that added this feature).

Comment: Are you able to post your code to set up the state machine? That would make it a lot easier for us to figure out the code to derive the states that precede a given state.

Comment: Is this even really possible? I'm not familiar with the gem itself, but what happens if there's multiple state paths? What would the desired behaviour be?

Comment: I'm with @SebastianLenartowicz - I'd be curious if this is even possible without explicitly defining what states come before `:ordered`...

Comment: @kcdragon unfortunately no, I can not post the code. However, the implementation is very straightforward, and I believe the states listed above provide enough of an example for what seems to be a rather universal need : how can one ask a model class *"are you in any state that comes before a given state?"*. 

The implementation is even less complex than the demonstrative implementation on the `state_machine` github page. So again, with the example: how can I get a list of all states before the `:ordered` state?

Comment: @SebastianLenartowicz and @CDub - After browsing some source code, I too believe this isnt directly possible, not without rolling my own mixin that utilizes the existing `state_machine` functionality. Its quite robust and sophisticated, but doesnt seem to provide this feature. 

My example explicitly defines what states come before `:ordered` : `[:pending, :signature_needed]`. My current solution is to just hard code those states into a boolean callback that checks if current `state` is in that array. I want it to be dynamic in case additional states are added in the future.

Comment: I have to agree with the others. This is a non-trivial problem. You'd have more concepts to wrestle with: path of transitions, cyclical transitions, branching. When the dust settles you're talking about something a) fairly complex and b) probably not as valuable. Is it enough to know what the acceptable immediately previous states are?

Comment: @jaydel and everyone else - can we please just assume it is a linear progression of those 4 states in the example above? Also, **I dont believe there is** any sort of functionality for `get_all_states_before(:state)`, for all the same reasons (non trivial, cyclical, etc). I am just making sure there isnt some sort of magic functionality my eyes overlooked :-). 

Any one of you can feel free to give a simple, "no, the gem does not directly provide this functionality" answer below :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such functionality built into the (currently unmaintained) `state_machine` gem. Since its entirely possible for non linear state transitions, it may be extremely complex, and quite unpredictable, to accurately describe "which state comes before another state." Thus, each application which makes use of the `state_machine` gem will need to create its own mixin to dynamically determine which states in the cycle come before and after each other.

Credit for answer goes to the comments below the OP.